# How to include a xhtml page into a Template in jsf

Tags: jsf, templates, facelets

I am trying to include a xhtml page into a Template content.Such that the content of template may contain the output of that xhtml file.
I don't how to include this,so please give me some suggestions.

`index.xhtml

```
    <ui:composition template="newTemplate.xhtml">
         <ui:define name="content"   ></ui:define></ui:composition>

</h:body>`
```

newTemplate.xhtml

```
    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="center_content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom">
        <ui:insert name="bottom">Bottom</ui:insert>
    </div>

</h:body>
`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template:

```
<ui:composition>  
       <ui:insert name="wa_content"></ui:insert>
</ui:composition>
```

xhtml page (with another include):

```
<ui:composition template="template_name">

        <ui:define name="wa_content" >
              <ui:define name="buttonsPanelBody" >
                        <ui:include src="other_xhtml_page_name.xhtml" />
              </ui:define>
        </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

other_xhtml_page_name.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
         your code
</ui:composition>
```